# Basic jquery toggleClass not working in es6 class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a menu that I want to show when an icon is clicked. I have the menu hidden by default when the page loads. I am using jQuerys `toggleClass()` method. When I click the icon the show class is never added to the `.menu`. The menu class highlights in the browser dev tools each time I click but no class is being added to it.

If I use the `addClass()` method then the class is added but I want to be able to toggle the `show` class so the menu is able to be shown and hidden while clicking the same icon/element.

HTML

```
<i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
<div class="menu">
  <div id="context-menu">
     <a href="#" type="button">Item 1</a>
     <a href="#" type="button">Item 2</a>
     <a href="#" type="button">Item 3</a>
     <a href="#" type="button">Item 4</a>   
  </div>
</div>
```

Menu.js

```
class Menu {
    constructor() {
        this.menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
        this.ellipsis = document.querySelector('.fa.fa-ellipsis-v');
        this.callEvent();
    }

    callEvent() {
        this.ellipsis.addEventListener('click',this.showMenu.bind(this));
    }

    showMenu(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $('.menu').toggleClass('show');
    }
}
```

CSS

```
.menu {
 display:none; 
}

.show{
 display:block;
}
```

Comment: if you want to make it work like it add !important to your display:block.

Comment: @Carlos1232 in my css my show class now looks like this ```.show {
  display: block !important;
}``` but the toggle still does nothing when the ellipsis is clicked.

Comment: In the code you posted you are missing the period before show in the CSS. I'm assuming this was a copy and paste problem posting here.

Comment: @imvain2 I apologize, I fixed that. My local css had the ```.``` before show, toggle still isn't working. Thanks!

Comment: I doubt this is the problem but something keeps catching my attention. Can you try this, replacing your clickhandler with is:

`this.ellipsis.addEventListener('click',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $('.menu').toggleClass('show');
});`

Comment: What is not working??

Comment: @epascarello jQuerys ```toggleClass()``` method is not adding or removing (since it is never added) my ```show``` class when I click the ellipsis

Comment: @imvain2 I tried out your code and it does the same thing, which is nothing. In the chrome dev tools, if I inspect the ```.menu``` div, I see the ```class=""``` light up each time I click but no class is being added.

Comment: What is some HTML? Code works fine for me when I ran it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be an answer but it really can't be a comment. I used your code, added a little css to make things viewable and guessed at the html (but that shouldn't make a difference). The code works as expected.

```js
class Menu {
    constructor() {
        this.menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
        this.ellipsis = document.querySelector('.fa.fa-ellipsis-v');
        this.callEvent();
    }

    callEvent() {
        this.ellipsis.addEventListener('click',this.showMenu.bind(this));
    }

    showMenu(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $('.menu').toggleClass('show');
    }
}

var menu = new Menu();
```

```css
.menu {
 display:none; 
 background-color: blue;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
}

.show{
 display:block;
}

.fa-ellipsis-v {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu"></div>
<span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v">...</span>
```

Comment: You're welcome? lol. I didn't change anything critical. Maybe you had a typo somewhere and it got fixed? just guessing.

Comment: I noticed I did not have this line ```const dummy = new Menu();``` so I was never instantiating the class. Weird but it works

Answer (score 1):

See below. I'm using `display:flex` instead of `display:block` for layout purposes.

```js
class Menu {
  constructor() {
    this.menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
    this.ellipsis = document.querySelector('.fa.fa-ellipsis-v');
    this.callEvent();
  }

  callEvent() {
    this.ellipsis.addEventListener('click', () => {
      $('.menu').toggleClass('show');
    });
  }
}

const dummy = new Menu();
```

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav>
  <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>This</li>
    <li>is</li>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>menu</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```